# Display stream of public Facebook posts without logging in

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I'm building a website, and I'd like to display a simple list of posts from my public facebook page. I got this working well using the GraphAPI and formatting the data on the server side, but then my access token expired.

Now I'm completely lost. It seems that there's no way to easily create a new access token. Can this possibly be true? Why would simply viewing the posts of a public page be restricted? Not only this, but even if I was willing to go with a pre-built facebook app for my webpage, they don't seem to have anything that displays the stream from your wall.

Thanks in advance for any clarification you might have to restore my sanity.

** **EDIT** **

Apparently the question is a little deeper than I thought at first. *I'm not building an app*. I just want to create a fairly basic list of a single user's posts on a webpage. Is there really no easy non-app way to do this? Learning facebook's server-side authentication flow seems a little intimidating for such a simple project.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this page: How-To: Handle expired access tokens https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

**EDIT:**

I think this should answer your question:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9663700/how-to-show-facebook-feed-messages-from-my-site/9663836#9663836

From playing around with this a bit, I can see that logging out destroys your access token and you can make a new one when you login again. It looks like the Graph API Explore is made for learning the Graph API. If you want an access token that persists, I think you will need to make a Facebook App and even those expire after a while and need to be refreshed (simple process).

Not sure how you're trying to display the posts on your site but Facebook Likebox or Activity Feed might achieve what you want. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

You could also try to use simpleXML to parse your page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: I'm not building an app. Would that still apply to me?

Comment: How did you get your access token?

Comment: From the Graph API explorer. I thought that token was to be used for anything. Apparently not?